# Streamed video frames going upside down

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm new to FFMPEG. I'd used:

`ffmpeg -re -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt bgr24 -i - -an -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://rtmp_url/app/instance`

this command. I'd got the successful streaming but the frames are distorted and moving upside down.

Below is the link to the snapshot of the frame.

[Image of the upside down frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVJzo.jpg)

Please help me out with this one.

Comment: Where are you piping from? My guess is your input height is set wrong. Some apps package 1080p in 1088 height frames.

Comment: @Gyan - I'm piping it with an OpenCV code from where ffmpeg is receiving the rawvideo and streaming it to the RTMP server. I tried setting the height to 1088 but it didn't work.

Comment: Hey @Gyan! Thanks a lot. It worked successfully. The problem was with the height as you've mentioned.